# Why does react input checkbox not check when ticking and unticking the checkbox?

Tags: checkbox, cypress

Cypress always reads it as checked if opened in edit mode and the checkbox was ticked previously and always reads it as unchecked during initial instance even if I tick it or untick it

This one is not working:

```
checkOnly.getCheckOnly().contains('test')
.siblings().children('input')
  .then(($ele) => {
    if (!($ele.is(':checked'))) {
      $ele.trigger("click")
    }
  })
```